# WPF-GridSplitter does not move

Tags: wpf

I have a Grid with 2 rows and in the first row 2 columns each with 2 rows.
The GridSplitter is inside the 2nd column. I do not know why the it does not move. I am thankfull for any help. ( I'm new here :-) )
With regards

Below XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="yyy:" Margin="10" MinWidth="50"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <TreeView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TreeView0"></TreeView>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="xxx:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="140"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <TreeView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TreeView1"></TreeView>
            <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="1" Width="2" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView Margin="10">              
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView></GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

After rearranging some rows and cloumns, I could solve my problem.

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="x:" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="50"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>       
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="y:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="140"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <TreeView x:Name="TreeView0"></TreeView>
                </Grid>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Grid Grid.Column="2">

                    <TreeView x:Name="TreeView1"></TreeView>                
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <ListView Margin="10">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView></GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

@Frisbee I am not ashamed to refer at MSDN or somewhere else. I came here in search of help. I did not ask you to fix my problem. Your approach of helping someone is realy disgusting and boaring. Instead of responding with rubbish words you could have concentrated on the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have the splitter in a row height *
Wrong

The splitter needs to be in an auto with height * above and below

Comment: Fix the question and follow directions

Comment: you mean a third row?

Comment: @Dano What part of * above and below is not clear.  There are example on MSDN.  Start with a simple example and make it work.

Comment: I have changed both row-heights with * ( above and below ) still
no movement. I hope you are not annoyed with my questions.

Comment: How can you change above and below when you don't have an above and below?  Post what you have done.   For the second time - start with a simple example from MSDN.

Comment: Above and below are meant the first and secon row. Both rows have now fixed values.
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
STILL NO CHANGE!
@Frisbee If you want to help someone, you have to concentrate on the issue. You do not have to play with words! 'Above' and 'Below' was from your answer and for sure you knew what I was trying to say.

Comment: I see that you did not understand my question and you did not see the XAML-code well. My problem is with a VERTICAL Gridsplitter!
It is self-explanatory not to set row height * for HORIZONTAL GridSplitter.
You do not have to refer MSDN too. If you have any solution to my problem Go ahead !

Comment: Your posted code has not changed.  If it self-explanatory not to set row height * for HORIZONTAL GridSplitter then why do you do that.   You are the one the need to refer to MSDN.

Comment: I need VERTICAL Gridsplitter NOT HORIZONTAL Gridsplitter!

Comment: I need VERTICAL Gridsplitter NOT HORIZONTAL Gridsplitter!
Beside that your first suggestion 
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
does not solve my problem. I do not have problem to refer to MSDN if have to. Instead of providing/suggesting solution you made unnecessary remarks and you distract the topic. I rest my case here.

Comment: Nothing in your question states horizontal or vertical.  What you have is closer to horizontal.   I am not going to help you as this is just a code dump and asking SO to fix it for you.   SO is not a code generation service.   Problems that show little or no research (and unrelated code) get little attention here.  And refusal to refer to MSDN will get you even less sympathy.